# Init called twice causing app to crash with error "An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer"

Tags: swift, swiftui, avplayer

I have a `NavigationStack` that consists of 3 views: a video selector, an upload progress view, and a video preview view. After uploading, I pass an `AVPlayerItem` to the preview view. This should then display the video. Here is the relevant code:

```
@main
struct CaptionsApp: App {
  @StateObject private var model = MyModel()

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      NavigationStack(path: $model.path) {
        VideoSelectorView(model: model)
          .navigationDestination(for: VideoDestination.self) { destination in
            switch destination {
            case .uploading:
              MyUploadView(model: model)
            case .transcribed(let playerItem):
              VideoPreviewView(playerItem: playerItem)
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }
}


struct VideoPreviewView: View {
  private var player: AVPlayer?

  init(playerItem: AVPlayerItem) {
    let player = AVPlayer(
      playerItem: playerItem
    )
    player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
    self.player = player
  }

  var body: some View {
    VideoPlayer(player: player)
      .onAppear {
        player.play()
      }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, when it navigates to the `VideoPreviewView`, it crashes with the error:

```
An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer
```

I checked and `init()` is called twice. I can't figure out why this could be. The navigation path is only ever added to once. The only `@Published` value changing in the model is the navigation path. How do I solve this?

Comment: Do not assume how many times your view's `init`s will be called. SwiftUI can call them however many times it likes. How about passing in an `AVPlayer` to the preview view, instead of an `AVPlayerItem`?

Comment: Update: Worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do not assume how many times your view's inits will be called. SwiftUI can call them however many times it likes. See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68633861/5133585).

You should write the `init` in a way that it doesn't matter how many times it is called. In this case, you can pass in the `AVPlayer` directly, instead of creating a new one.

```
struct VideoPreviewView: View {
  private var player: AVPlayer

  init(player: AVPlayer) {
    self.player = player
    player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
  }
}
```

Initialise the player in the switch instead.

```
case .transcribed(let playerItem):
  VideoPreviewView(player: AVPlayer(playerItem: playItem))
```